# When I run my rust application on windows the coloring works with cargo run but it compeltely breaks when directly using the binary. Why?

Tags: rust

On mac the coloring is perfect regardless it only breaks on windows and in a very very weird way. When running the application with cargo run or cargo run --release the coloring is perfect (As seen in picture)

[image: Terminal text with working colors]

but when just running the binary directly on windows coloring completely breaks (As seen in picture)!

[image: Terminal text with broken colors]

The code for the help menu is:

```rust
        //NovusCLI Help
        println!("\n[1mNovusCLI Help[0m\n");
        //nvs search <query>
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33msearch <query>[0m\t\t\tSearches for specified query");
        //nvs list [--flag(s)] <package(s)>
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mlist [--flag(s)] <package(s)>[0m\tLists specified packages");
        //nvs info <package(s)>
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33minfo <package(s)>[0m\t\t\tDisplay info on specified package(s)");
        //nvs install <package(s)>
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33minstall <package(s)>[0m\t\tInstalls specified package(s)");
        //nvs reinstall <package(s)>
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mreinstall <package(s)>[0m\t\tReinstalls specified package(s)");
        //nvs remove <package(s)>
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mremove <package(s)>[0m\t\t\tRemoves specified package(s)");
        //nvs add-key <filepath>
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33madd-key <filepath>[0m\t\t\tAdds a key to the list of trusted keys");
        //nvs edit-sources
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33medit-sources[0m\t\t\tOpens the APT repo editor");
        //nvs autoremove
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mautoremove[0m\t\t\t\tRemoves unneeded packages (orphans)");
        //nvs update
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mupdate[0m\t\t\t\tUpdates the repository lists");
        //nvs upgrade <package(s)>
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mupgrade <package(s)>[0m\t\tUpgrades specified packages");
        //nvs full-upgrade <package(s)>
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mfull-upgrade <package(s)>[0m\t\tUpgrades the system (or package(s))");
        //nvs version
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mversion[0m\t\t\t\tDisplay APT, DPKG, and NovusCLI versions");
        //nvs clean
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mclean[0m\t\t\t\tClears the download cache");
        //nvs help <command>
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mhelp <command>[0m\t\t\tOpens help menu for specified commands");
        //nvs about
        println!("[1;35mnvs [0m[1;33mabout[0m\t\t\t\tView legal information and credits\n");
```

I know I could just use a rust crate to handle the coloring for me but all coloring crates that support windows that I could find either use libc or winapi which are both unsafe which is why I refuse to use any of these crates for coloring. Does anybody know why using the bin directly on windows breaks all coloring? I tried on both Command Prompt and Windows PowerShell and both have the exact same problem.

I entered all the code for the help menu but stackoverflow seems to be hiding the special characters so here's a pastebin link to the code:

https://pastebin.com/Gz2GwunR

and here's a picture of the code:

[image: Picture of help menu code with special characters]

Comment: I think windows console has poor support for ANSI codes, cargo must be doing some kind of emulation tho

Comment: Don't hardcode terminal control sequences. They don't always work, as you have just discovered.

Comment: @n.m. well what do I do then?

Comment: There are libraries. https://users.rust-lang.org/t/colored-terminal-output/24604/3

Answer (score 3):

Windows support for VT100 escape sequences (your color codes) was only added with some rather recent update of Windows 10 and must be enabled explicitly for each app, via native API. This is done via the [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) function with the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT` argument. An alternative way is using the [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) function to set the terminal color directly -- this variant also works on older Windows versions. Obviously, both of these require unsafe code.

Generally speaking, I wouldn't recommend rejecting libraries simply based on the fact that they contain unsafe code. As demonstrated with this very example, some things simply can't be achieved without it. Also, the Rust standard library makes heavy use of `unsafe` as well.